# Read notifications table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am making a notifications table. That is structured like this:

```
notifications:    
+----+------+----------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------+
| ID | user | notification         | message                           | timestamp |
+----+------+----------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------+
| 1  | 6    | Denied acceptance    | You have been denied for...       |           |
| 2  | 6    | Apreooved acceptance | You have been accepted...         |           |
| 3  | 0    | Open slots           | there are still open slots for... |           |
+----+------+----------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------+
```

And a table that indicates which notification was read by each user

```
notifications_read    
+----+------+--------------+-----------+
| ID | user | notification | timestamp |
+----+------+--------------+-----------+
| 1  | 6    | 2            |           |
+----+------+--------------+-----------+
```

If notification is meant only for one user, there is a user id under "user" in "notifications"- If the notification is meant for everybody I insert '0' under user.

I am trying to make a query that selects rows from "notifications", that is not read.

My current query is not ok:

```
SELECT * 
FROM notifications 
WHERE id NOT IN 
    (SELECT notification 
     FROM notification_read 
     WHERE user = $id) AND user = $id OR user = 0
```

So for above table it needs to select the rows with id 1 & 3

Thank you for the help!

Comment: What does "not read" mean when a notification is meant for all users?  Are you only looking for unread notifications for a particular user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want unread notifications for a particular user, then you are on the right track:

```
SELECT n.* 
FROM notifications n
WHERE n.id NOT IN (SELECT nr.notification 
                   FROM notification_read nr
                   WHERE nr.user = $id) AND
      (n.user = $id OR n.user = 0);
```

I think the only issue is the parentheses for the logic around `OR`.

You can also write this using `IN`:

```
SELECT n.* 
FROM notifications n
WHERE n.id NOT IN (SELECT nr.notification 
                   FROM notification_read nr
                   WHERE nr.user = $id) AND
      n.user IN (0, $id);
```

Comment: Your solution is promissing..I will test it on several combinations in the tables.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT n.*
FROM notifications n
LEFT JOIN notifications_read nr ON nr.notification = n.id
WHERE
nr.id IS NULL
```

This will give you notifications that don't exist n the notifications_read table.

Left join will give you all rows in notifications and join rows from notifications_read that have a notification id.  So when you filter by `nr.id IS NULL` you will return rows that exist in `notifications` but not in `notifications_read`.

Additionally, the LEFT JOIN will perform better.

> A LEFT [OUTER] JOIN can be faster than an equivalent subquery because the server might be able to optimize it better—a fact that is not specific to MySQL Server alone.
>   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/rewriting-subqueries.html